# Groups and automorphisms of group-1

Tags: group-theory

Why valid results don't understand for groups $V$ seen as automorphisms of group
$G$ is also valid when it is considered those groups as subgrupos of $G$.
For instance, the following result is true:

(to see An Introduction the Theory of Finite Groups,Kurzweil and Bernd Stellmacher)

(A) Let be $V\leq \operatorname{Aut}\left( G\right),\ N\vartriangleleft G$ and $V$-invariant.
Consider the semidirect product of $V$ with $G$. Let
$C_{G}(V)=\{g\in G:g^{v}=g\}$. For finite groups the following applies:

> If $(|V|,|G|)=1$, then $C_{G/N}(V)=C_{G}(V)N/N$.

Assuming (A), because (B) it is true??

> (B) Let be $K$ a subgroup of $G$,  $N\vartriangleleft G$ and $K$ normalizer $N$.
>    Let $C_{G}(K)=\{g\in G:g^{k}=g\}$. Thus,
>
> If $(|K|,|G|)=1$, then  $C_{G/N}(K)=C_{G}(K)N/N$.

"Excuse!
English is not my origin language."

Comment: I think you should write
$$
C_{G}(V)=\{g\in G:g^{v}=g \text{, for all $v \in V$}\},
$$
and similarly for $C_{G}(K)$.

Comment: User2040: Yes!Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have (A), note that in (B) $C_{G}(K)$ is the same thing as $C_{G}(V)$, where $V$ is the image of $K$ in $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$. In fact an element $k \in K$ is mapped onto the inner automorphism $x \mapsto x^{k}$.

A similar argument holds for $C_{G/N}(K)$.

Comment: But $\psi:K\rightarrow InnG$, $k\mapsto \gamma_{k}$ not is isomorphism. Would not that be a problem?

Comment: @User2040, I do not think so, $$C_{G}(K)=\{g\in G:g^{k}=g \text{, for all $k \in K$}\}=\{g\in G:g^{\psi(k)}=g \text{, for all $\psi(k) \in V = \psi(K)$}\}  = C_{G}(V)$$.

Comment: User2040: You are really right. Now I understood. Thank you!

Comment: @User2040, you're welcome!